# Can't come up with a Rails-ish boolean column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

A "group" belongs to a "owner" and has many "members". Both the "owner" and the "members" can create "events" under the "group."

Then I need to restrict members to create events under particular groups.

So I tried to add a boolean column to groups table:

- When true - this "group" allow all "members" to create "events."
- When false - this "group" doesn't allow "members" to create "events", which means only "owner" can create events.

but what should this column name be like?

- allows_members_to_create_events
- allows_only_owner_to_create_events
- requires_owner_authority_to_create_events
- other ones?

Or am I doing something wrong with my database design?

I know I'm a little bit too picky about naming but I always have trouble with this kind of naming problem and waste times. So I asked here.

Comment: You might get better answers on finding the correct work with a specific meaning at http://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good name is one of the hardest things to do in coding and I too spend silly time mulling over good naming.

One of my judging criterion is see how the name is being used.

In database point of view i.e. reading from the model source code, `only_owner_can_create` is a good explanatory name.

In controller point of view, you may want to write `if group.allows_members_to_create?` or `unless group.only_owner_can_create`

Having the context where this field will be used will help you greatly to determine the name.

Also you CAN have the best of both worlds - just use alias_methods to add more methods!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of boolean column add numeric column to hold some numeric values. This numeric values are inserted based on the their levels. You have to define these levels in you application.

Comment: I didn't think of this idea. But I decided to stick to a boolean column. Thanks Mohanraj anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`member_can_create_events` would be my pick (single data point that I am).
That would give:

```
my_group.members_can_create_events?
```

Though I also agree with Mohanraj that a more complete solution might have users with levels and a column that relates to  "users over level X can create events here"... but if you want a quick solution, the boolean column works just fine.